# Sample size estimation for difference-indifference design with continuous outcome

Tags: sample-size, difference-in-difference

I have spent some time looking for a package in R to estimate the required sample size for a difference-in-difference design with continuous outcome. However, I could not find any package. Is there a package available that I have overlooked? Or is there a procedure in Stata 15? Thanks a lot for your guidance on this matter in advance.

Best

Michael

Comment: A difference-in-differences analysis is equivalent to a regression model with two binary predictors + an interaction term. You would want to choose the sample size to achieve the desired power to detect the interaction. Or equivalently search for power analysis of a two-way ANOVA with an interaction.